# Sending MMS programmatically in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sms, mms

Is there any way to send MMS programmatically in iPhone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to send a picture message using iPhone SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150271/is-it-possible-to-send-a-picture-message-using-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is, not with the current SDK anyways. You can only prefill SMS messages in the Messages app using UIApplication's openURL: method.

Comment: you cannot prefill SMS messages, only ONE and ONLY phone number to send the SMS. I checked this recently on Developers Forum. There was an answer from an Apple employee, that we should fill a bug report with an enhancement request...

Answer (score 2):

mobilesubstrate + jailbreaking + .dylib = yes

xcode + apple + .app = nope

if you dont care that it is unapprovable and want to do something for cydia instead then go with the first part. if not, youre kinda at a loss, sorry.

Comment: I have got another alternative. 
We can make request from iphone/ipod to php server and send sms from the server.The server script will handle the sending of sms

Comment: Yes that would be a solution, though TECHNICALY it would not be mms, but it works none the less

Answer (score 0):

I Think sending MMS is now available for iPhone-3G and iPhone-3GS.older version of iPhone can only view MMS but can't Send MMS.