# Sending MMS in my iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.1, mms

hope you all are enjoying.

Recently i come to know that now iPhone 3G and iPhone 3GS support MMS sending and receiving functionality.

I have seen a video in which Apple's native Message Application sent MMS.

Same MMS functionality I want to integrate with my Application.

I Don't know how can I put it working.

Need help of you guys!!.

Looking forwards.

Thank You,

Arun Thakkar.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576253/sending-mms-programatically-in-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately You can't send MMS from your application. There is no URL register scheme for that. SMS can be sent with register scheme to any Recipient number , but No body.

Alternate way to is open SMS interface and let the User choose Image/Video as attachment. Then SMS will automatically be converted into MMS.

Thanks n Enjoy

Pratik Goswami.

Comment: Thanks pratik for your reply!! I have also one query that, suppose i have a url where my mms video lies, I want to play that Streamed mms. 

so how its possible? have you any idea regarding this?

Comment: AFAIK MMS will be either Image or Video or both. If it is Video then go for video streming.

Comment: Is this still valid? I think that in ios4 sdk there's a new framework that gives you more access to mms and sms interfaces.

Comment: MMS not available in app as of iOS 6