# How can we send MMS attachments from our iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mms

In my application i want to send a attachments, Test through MMS. How can we do it using iPhone SDK. Please help me out.

Thank you

Comment: This is close to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576253/sending-mms-programatically-in-iphone , but it doesn't ask about attachments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't, at least not in a supported way that you would get away with on the App Store.