# Is it possible to send a picture message using iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, mms

Is it possible to send an MMS message with a picture using the iPhone SDK? After looking at MFMessageComposeViewController, it doesn't appear to be possible.

Comment: You can send MMS. Just please look at this answer which i had posted here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12739608/1443976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes thats true there is still no API for sending mms in iphone.But the only option left is to attach the image in mail composer

Answer (score 0):

I think, the iphone has no public API for sending MMS. Only way you can achieve this is to use a providers MMS gateway directly, but this would not work worldwide.

Alternate way to is open SMS interface and let the User choose Image/Video as attachment. Then SMS will automatically be converted into MMS.

Comment: How u can choose image as attachment?  I mean ,I need procedure.If u have any code for that put it here Plz.. @iHS