# For the current iphone version,  MMS is possible or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to send a picture message using iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150271/is-it-possible-to-send-a-picture-message-using-iphone-sdk)

Hi all ,
does MMS way of sending images/text is possible in iPhone ?/
i have used SMS and mail for sending images im just want to make things for MMS .
is there any way to send MMS programmatically??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) does not support MMS, there is no other way then to create you own MMS gateway to allow your app to support MMS.